# Open Div on click then leave it open when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following

```
 $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#click").click(function() {
            $("#top").toggle();
        });
    });


<div id="click"><img src="/files/images/x.jpg" alt="x"/>Click to open</div>
    <div id="top"Some information></div>
```

What I want is the div to stay open when clicked or the page is reloaded again.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you do not want the div to get hidden if clicked again?

Comment: *What I want is the div to stay open when clicked* So don't use `toggle`. Just `show` your div.

Comment: I do understand this part *`What I want is the div to stay open when clicked`* but not this part *`or the page is reloaded again`*. Did you mean that once your div has been open, its state will be persistently open even when the page is reloaded, am I correct ?

Comment: @MeteorZero That is what I wanted, however I realise that the documentr.ready prevents that so I need to find another solution, thanks again for looking, however if you know how to do that that would be great though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#click").click(function() {
            $("#top").show();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="click"><img src="/files/images/x.jpg" alt="x"/>Click to open</div>
<div id="top" style="display: none;"> Some information</div>
```

This way the Top-Div will stayed open even if you click on #click twice or more than once.

Comment: Thanks so much just what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, I guess you need to use the cookie. Set the cookie with the flag if the popup is opened or closed on click event trigger and on DOM ready event check if for the variable if the value has set to open then trigger the popup open action or else keep it closed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling toggle function add a class (eg. opened) to the div. Using CSS add display:none; to the div and display:block; to the opened class.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#click").click(function() {
            $("#top").addClass('opened');
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
#top { display: none; }
#top.opened { display: block; }
</style>

<div id="click"><img src="/files/images/x.jpg" alt="x"/>Click to open</div>
<div id="top"> Some information</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With toogle you will close it the second click. The open the third and so on. Just change it to show().

```
$("#top").show();
```

About keep it opened when you refresh the page you can use local storage, or cookies or whatever client side, but it will be kept only in the current browser. Otherwise you have to store the status through an AJAX request to the server and get back the value.